# List a variable range of tabs

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get a list of the names of the sheets starting from a specific sheet, as I don't need the names of the tabs before that sheet. The problem is that these sheets will have variable length and sheet name from quarter to quarter (they might change name and decrease or increase in number).

This is what I have done but I get it wrong, but mind that my VBA level is null.

Sub XX1()

```
Dim x As Integer

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim WKS As Worksheet: Set WKS = wb.Sheets("10")
x = 1

 For Each WKS In Worksheets
 Sheets("Directory").Cells(x, 1) = WKS.Name
 x = x + 1
```

Next WKS

End Sub

I want to get, from the sheet called S (is the sheet number 10), all the sheet names and list them in another sheet, called 'Directory'.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the `Worksheets.Index` attribute to do this.
Here it is:

```
Sub XX1()

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wks = wb.Sheets("10")
    x = 1
    
    For Each sh In Worksheets
        If sh.Index >= wks.Index Then
            Sheets("Directory").Cells(x, 1).Value = sh.Name
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Next sh

End Sub
```

Obviously the result will change if you manually move the worksheets in your workbook.